# Facebook Messenger webhook in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson, watson-iot, watson-dialog

I am developing a chatbot in IBM Bluemix. When I try to integrate with Facebook Messenger, it asks about webhook.

I am just running a [simple app](https://github.com/cyrillebenoit/conversationMaster), available on GitHub.

I want to know how to integrate Messenger with Watson conversation API.

[image: Environment variables]

Answer (score 0):

The web hook is the API (GET and POST) in your application that Facebook, and your application, will use to handshake and send Messenger messages to your application.

Its not too difficult to set-up, there is a good set of instructions that come with a Node-RED node for Facebook messenger - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-facebook-messenger-writer

Answer (score 0):

Adding to that, you can also look at middleware plugin that allows developers to easily integrate a Watson Conversation workspace with multiple social channels like Slack, Facebook, and Twilio. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware